# How to use Parameters in xsl:apply-templates which are set from java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, transform

I have a question on how to dynamically set the xpath expression in apply-templates select=?

```
<xsl:template match="CDS">
        <xsl:result-document href="{$fileName}">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$xpathCondition"/>
            </xsl:copy>

        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
```

This $xpathCondition am trying to set from java from properties file and setting to param in xsl.

```
        transformer.setParameter("fileName", "Test.xml");
        transformer.setParameter("xpathCondition", "CD[contains(Title/text(),'TEST')]");
```

$fileName is working as expected. But $xpathCondition is not working as expected.

Comment: Related: [dynamic xpath in xslt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630023/dynamic-xpath-in-xslt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be tackled in XSLT 3.0 using static parameters and shadow attributes. You can write:

```
<xsl:param name="xpathCondition" static="yes"/>
```

and then:

```
<xsl:apply-templates _select="{$xpathCondition}"/>
```

(Note the underscore in `_select`)

With 2.0 (or indeed 1.0) you can simulate this approach by doing a transformation on the stylesheet before executing it.

Comment: Am trying to use this solution. I changed XSLT Version to 3.0, Still facing the below exception : 

`Error at xsl:apply-templates on line 16 of Transform.xslt:
  XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 16 in {}:
    Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression`

Comment: In java am setting the parameter as 
`transformer.setParameter("xpathCondition", "CD[contains(Title/text(),'TEST')]");`

Comment: Static parameters need to be provided at compile time, not at run-time. You'll therefore need to use the s9api interface rather than JAXP, calling XsltCompiler.setParameter().

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way of parsing a string as a dynamic XPath expression and executing it until you get to the xsl:evaluate instruction in XSLT 3.0. You really need to tell us which version you are using - the fact that you use xsl:result-document tells us that it's 2.0 or later, but beyond that we are guessing.

Many XSLT processors have an extension function called xx:eval() or similar.

Comment: Am using stylesheet version - 2.0.

Comment: @JohnCarter Which XSLT processor specifically?